# Having a user's changes actually saved to the code

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js

I'm working on a website currently and I was wondering if there is any way that a user could actually edit the code for the site. For example, services like WordPress or Squarespace allow users to edit text and it be saved on their live website, I was wondering how they achieve this and how I could implement this into my site.
Are they even actually allowing the code to be edited, or does it just look like it due to what's saved in a database somewhere? Or is the entire page worth of code uploaded to a database, and then it's loaded into the page via something like handlebars? Is there a best practice in this regard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [How to develop a content management system](https://jayamwebsolutions.com/blogs/How-to-develop-a-CMS-Content-Management-System.html)

Comment: I don't have much experience with Squarespace but for WordPress, you almost never edit the code but rather the content (with some exceptions). When you add/edit posts, comments, articles etc. it all can be saved on a DB. For settings such as colours and appearance in general, you can have a separate table and save them there. However, when you edit theme code (headers.php, footers.php etc.). It does not make any sense to save them on the database. You can start by storing some settings such as logos, colours, fonts etc. in a table as well as posts comments and articles.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! This is definitely the explanation I needed